# Using ExtJs how to get the selected index text of a select box item?

Tags: extjs

I want to get the text of a selected index item of a combo box using ExtJs. I have tried various methids and none of them are working.

```
My select box is something like below
<select name="xxx" id="xxId">
<option value='1'>ONE</option>
<option value='2'>TWO</option>
</select>
```

And below is the code which i have tried

```
var idValue = this.getValue();
var index = this.getStore().indexOf(idValue);
alert(index);
```

Can one suggest a way to do this?

Comment: I have resolved this using below extJs property.
this.lastSelectionText

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it. In extJs, we can use the property

```
this.lastSelectionText
```